# ¿como es el comportamiento del pattern en javascript y que tiene que ver con setCustomValidity()?

Tags: java, regex, funciones

[este es mi archivo pruebenlo si quieren](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fsYZ7gPVp9tbLt_Wcqj-qDIYoMAsw9XV)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 var edad;
 function comenzar() {
 
  edad=document.getElementById("edad");
  edad.addEventListener("change",cambia_rango,false);

  document.registroUser.addEventListener("invalid",validar,true);//el evento invalid se desencadena cuando no se ha validado algun elemento del formulario.
  document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click",enviar,false);
  //document.registroUser.addEventListener("input",validar_tiempo_real,false);

 }
 function cambia_rango(){//llamando a la funcion
  var mirango = document.getElementById("rango");//obteniendo el output
  var calculo = edad.value-10;
  if (calculo<=0) {
   edad.value=10;
   calculo=0;
  }else{
   mirango.innerHTML = calculo + " a " + edad.value;//escribiendo en el output
  }
 }
 
 function validar(error){//LLAMANDO AL OBJETO ERROR QUE SE CREA EN EL EVENTO INVALID
  var element_error=error.target;//elemento que esta mal. se identifica el error
  element_error.style.background="tomato";
  if (isNaN(element_error.value)) {
   element_error.style.background="white";
  }
 }
 function enviar(){
  var es_correcto=document.registroUser.checkValidity();
  if (es_correcto) {
   document.registroUser.submit();
  }
 }
 function validar_tiempo_real(error){
  var elemento_equivocado=error.target;
  if(elemento_equivocado.validity.valid == true){

   elemento_equivocado.style.background="white";

  }else{
   elemento_equivocado.style.background="tomato";
  }
 }

window.addEventListener("load",comenzar,false);
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
 table{
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
 }
 td{
  padding: 10px 5px;
 }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Mi APIS DE FORMULARIO</title>
</head>
<body>

 <form name="registroUser" method="get">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Usuario: <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" name="nombre" id="nombre"></td>
   </tr>
    
   <tr>
    <td>Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  ></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Edad: <input type="range" name="edad" id="edad" min="0" max="100" value="10" step="10"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><output id="rango" name="rango_edad">0  a  10</output></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Telefono: <input type="tel" name="telefono" id="telefono" 
     pattern="[0-9]{9}" required="true"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="boton" value="Enviar" id="enviar"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

*el error es que cuando se hace la validación del pattern en usuario, pues me aparece el serCustomValue predeterminado ,incluso si esta bien el valor que esta en el input usuario, pero la verdad no se por que, parece que el patrón me deniega todo.Personalmente creo que el error esta en la funcion validar pues es el unico que pone en rojo el invalido.*
*la verdad creo que el codigo esta bien solo que la función validar() esta haciendo algo creo.pues creo que el patron: pattern="[A-Za-z]" esta bien , es sencillo,no se por que me sigue apareciendo el aviso de que siga el patron*

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, se trata que pues el atributo pattern funciona por taamao de caracteres, siginifica que como yo puse pattern="[a-zA-Z]" pues estaba solo admitiendo para 1 caracter, pero yo queria un nombre de usuario y pues el patron de 1 caracter no sirve, por lo que debio ser :
pattern="[a-zA-Z]{#num_caracteres}"
eso fue todo
el setCustomValue("") me botaba el error pues yo siempre  metia mas de u caraacter y pues siempre iba a salir el mensaje si esque yo o metia solo un 1 caracter.